# clicking inner div to trigger outer div event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling

I have a React functional component that returns a div containing child divs. It comprises an *Item*, and is used by another component to populate a list of *Item* rows. That list component gives each item an *onClick* event function, which I've placed on the outer div of each *Item*:

```
import React from 'react';

const Item = props => {
  const { itemid, data, onClick } = props;
  
  return (
    <div itemid={itemid} type="button" tabIndex={0} onKeyPress={onClick} role="button" onClick={onClick}>
      <div>
        {itemid}
      </div>
      <div>
        {data}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Item;
```

My thought is each entire *Item* row (both inner divs), when clicked, should trigger the *onClick* event attached to the outer div. But nope - the inner divs above do not apparently inherit the *onClick* event from the outer div.

The *onClick* event is only triggered by the inner divs if I attach it to them directly.

Is there some way to have the inner divs inherit the *onClick* attached to the outer div?

Comment: out of curiosity, may I ask why you want to implement that behavior ? It's just something I've never thought of

Comment: If you decide that for some reason you're not going to be able to make the `onKeyPress` event bubble up to the outer div, maybe you could dispatch a custom event (with `bubbles: true`) and listen for that event instead of `onKeyPress` in the outer div? It's kinda hacky, I know.

Comment: @Duc Hong I want to be able to select any individual row. The click handler takes the id of the row clicked to tell the List which row was selected. Maybe there's a better way to do this.

Comment: now I see your scenario, usually you only need one onClick handler on each row, and passing the unique id of that row to the onClick handler. Then in the handler, you can retrieve the clicked row from a stored data, like this `const onClickHandler = (event, uid) => console.log('data: ', data[uid])` , does this make sense ?

Comment: from there, you can have a list storing the selected rows, manipulating that list is the only thing you consider in this case

Comment: Sounds like that might work. But actually, i just found a solution. For the child divs, if I add "...style={{ pointerEvents: 'none'}}", that apparently keeps the div from being clickable, so the outer div then takes the click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this seems to solve my problem:

```
import React from 'react';

const Item = props => {
  const { itemid, data, onClick } = props;
  
  return (
    <div itemid={itemid} type="button" tabIndex={0} onKeyPress={onClick} role="button" onClick={onClick}>
      <div style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}>
        {itemid}
      </div>
      <div style={{ pointerEvents: 'none' }}>
        {data}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Item;
```

I guess the [pointerEvents: 'none'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) keeps the child divs from being clickable, so the outer div then takes the click.

Still hoping for a better solution, as this seems a little strange.

Comment: actually the root cause here is to stop event propagation in those `div` children. Once set that with `e.stopPropagation();`, your child handler can work on its own, while you still can bind a click event on the parent. and having a checking with `event.target` in parent event handler will prevent strange bugs in case

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by **@DucHong** `e.stopPropagation()` will prevent the parent element clicks if you put it in the click event of the child element.

```
        import React, { useState } from "react";
        import './RowForm.css';
        import { BsFillCheckSquareFill } from "react-icons/bs"
        import { BookmarkTransaction, ChangeFormData, ClearTransaction } from "../../Accounts/Store/accountsSlice";

       ...
       ...
       ...

        <tr
            key={id}
            onClick={(e) => {
                dispatch(ChangeFormData({
                    isChecked: true,
                    formData: getValues()
                }))
            }}
        >
            <th className="checkbox-th">
                <FormGroup check className="mt-2">
                    {isChecked ?
                        <BsFillCheckSquareFill
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                e.stopPropagation()
                                dispatch(ChangeFormData({
                                    isChecked: false,
                                    formData: getValues()
                                }))
                            }}
                            className='check-icon'
                        />
                        :
                        <div
                            onClick={(e) => {
                                console.log("===>true bottom")
                                e.stopPropagation()
                                dispatch(ChangeFormData({
                                    isChecked: true,
                                    formData: getValues()
                                }))
                            }}
                            className='checkbox-wrapper'
                        />
                    }
                </FormGroup>
            </th>
       </tr>

       ...
       ...
       ...
```